# no mouse movement or touch in kivy app run from cli in raspberry

Tags: kivy, raspberry-pi3, multi-touch

I'm just starting with Kivy - I have issues getting the mouse and (multi)touchfunctionality to work.
Setup: RPi 3b v1.2, Raspberry os buster 5.4 with desktop & python 3.7.3, using Waveshare DSI touch display
Waveshare display drivers were installed: https://github.com/waveshare/LCD-show

Kivy is installed in virtualenv, which I start with source /home/wannes/kivy_venv/bin/activate ('wannes' being my username)
Kivy examples are in ~/.local/share/kivy-examples/demo/showcase

I've added this to ~/.kivy/config.ini:

```
[modules]
touchring = show_cursor=true
[input]
mouse = mouse
#%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=hidinput
mtdev_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=mtdev
hid_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=hidinput
```

When running Kivy apps on the gui (using the e.f. the Kivy showcase example app), I can move around and click with my mouse, but not use the touch or multitouch functionality - I can simulate that with right-mouseclick.

I've been looking around, and I tried with the 'xhost +local:root' command - that give me an error: 'xhost: unable to open display""'

For running Kivy in clu, I did 'sudo usermod -a -G video $(whoami)' to avoid the 'failed to open vchiq instance' error
here in cli I can also run Kivy apps - the apps open, but I have no mouse movement, click or touch whatsoever.
There is no error, just no mouse or touch when running the Kivy apps straight from the cli.

Any thoughts as to:

- why there is no mouse click or (multi)-touch functionality when running Kivy in x
- why there is even no mouse movement when running Kivy apps from cli?

THANKS!!!

Comment: After digging, I found a clue: when I completely reinstall the Pi (Raspberry OS w/ desktop) and use the default user pi to install and run Kivy (still using the config changes for Kivy) it works!
In the setup file for Kivy there are a lot of HARDCODED references to the pi user - for the moment, I can't get it to work with my own user though...
Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.
First, the waveshare driver has to be setup with the pi user and not any other - in their driver setup files the user pi is hardcoded...
Then, the user (other than pi) with which you want to run the Kivy apps, has to be member of the 'input' group: sudo usermod -a -G input $(whoami)
Kivy needs access to /dev/input/event0 /event4 and /event5
Waveshare setup give only the pi user access to the input group, which has read access to those devices.
Problem solved - at least there is little documentation from Waveshare for setup of their touch driver.